# Conditional Find and Replace in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex

Example data:

```
A    B
------
1    HELLO
2    HELLO
2    HELLO
3    HELLO
```

I want to replace `$` with `, WORLD!` but only if A is equal to 2. Such that the final result would be:

```
A    B
------
1    HELLO
2    HELLO, WORLD!
2    HELLO, WORLD!
3    HELLO
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following arrayformula in conjunction with 2 nested `IF` functions. Adjust ranges to your needs:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(P2:P<>"", 
           IF(P2:P=2,Q2&", WORLD",Q2),""))
```

[image]